# writable folder with 755 permissions

Tags: permissions, nginx

Do you know how to setup writable `folderA` within `/usr/share/nginx/html` having folder permissions `755`?

I don't want to use `775` or `777` permissions due to security reasons.

The user of nginx is also `nginx` and the `folderA` is owned by `nginx:nginx`.

Comment: Writable by whom? Why not 755?

Comment: Writable by nginx user

Comment: That contradicts your requirements. 755 = writable only by user. 775 = writable by user and group.

Comment: You're right ... I modified my comments to nginx user only

Comment: My understanding is that nginx user is considered belonging to "others" hence despite 755 permissions directory remains unwritable for it.

Comment: "The user of nginx is also nginx and the folderA is owned by nginx:nginx. "   folderA IS writable by nginx with permissions 755. I would even go for 750 myself ;)  1 thing: make sure `/usr/share/nginx/` is set properly too. "My understanding is that nginx user is considered belonging to "others" hence despite 755 permissions directory remains unwritable for it." Not if it is a user (or a group). If it is not a user then yes. So create the user (and without a /home).

Comment: @BubbaYakoza that is incorrect. Maybe you should post your actual problem instead of what you think  your problem is.

Comment: The problem is that nginx user fails to write to folderA ... folderA is owned by nginx:nginx and folder permissions are 755 ... this is a fresh installation of LEMP

Comment: nginx does not write anything, are you using php ? What are the permissions of all directories ? Is apparmor preventing write access ?

Comment: Yes! It's PHP application ... permissions of all directories are 755 ... SELinux is disabled ... I'm not sure about apparmor ... OS is centos 7